# Can't get UIWebView to play a .mp4 in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, interface-builder, xcode4.3

I'm displaying a webview like this:

```
NSString * nsstrPath = [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource : page ofType : @"html" ] ;
NSURL    * nsURL = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath : nsstrPath ] ;
NSURLRequest     * nsURLRequest = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL : nsURL ] ;
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
[ webView loadRequest : nsURLRequest ] ;
```

The webview loads the locally stored html file perfectly.  Here is the HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    <p align="center"><video src="videotest.mp4" poster="ImageTest.png" controls="controls"></video></p>
    <p>Testing</p>
    <img src="ImageTest.png">

</body>
</html>
```

I imported both the .mp4 file and the .png file into my Xcode project the same way, the .png file displays in the UIWebview just fine, the Video however show's a crossed out play symbol (indicating that the video can't be found).

I double and triple checked the names, the video has been created with an iOS supported codec.  I can't figure out why in the world it can't play the video file.

If I right click on the HTML file and select "Show in Finder" I can open the HTML file on my computer and the video plays just fine, just on iOS devices it wont load or play.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you drag your movie-files into XCode a dialog appears. Make sure you tick your app under "add to targets" there.

Or if you already copied your video into the project, if you click it in Xcode's file browser, you'll have an option on the right-hand side to select targets (again - make sure your app is ticked)